# How to check If current logged in user is in SharePoint group or not in info path 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath

I have SharePoint list and want to hide some of the columns based on SharePoint group role. And i have created this list in info path 2013. But I want to hide these columns from info path by checking if current logged in user is in SharePoint group or not?

**For example:**

I have 5 columns in SharePoint List: Name, Email, Address, Contact and DOB,
and I have a SharePoint Group called "Full Viewer".

**And My Condition is:**

if logged in user is in "Full Viewer" group then show all the fields otherwise hide Address, Contact and DOB fields. 
How can I achieve this in info path 2013 or any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution of this question. what I did was:

1. I created a SharePoint list called "authenticated user" and add authenticated users there.
2. And in Info Path, I have added the data source "authenticated user" and created a form load rule to set IsAuthenticatedUser field true or false by filtering a logged in user is in that data source list or not.
3. And finally I went to the Name field and add a rule to check if isAuthenticated user is blank then hide this control otherwise not. same is applied for other fields Email, Address, Contact and DOB etc.

Please find the blow link for further reference with screenshots.

[Click here.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32515.restrict-infopath-section-visibility-based-on-user.aspx)